# Flow: Use the types from connect to deduct the props' types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

Simple example:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
  error: state.error, // error: ?string
})

type Props = {
  error: number, // wrong type!
}

class HelloWorld extends Component<Props> { ... }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HelloWorld)
```

My issues:

1. Not DRY: `error` comes from the Redux's state and its type is already specified in `State`
2. Should be `?string` but we can put anything, possibly causing a bug

Is there any way to tell Flow "this prop is coming from the state so take the same type"?

Something like

```
type Props = PropsFromConnect // { error: ?string }
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some hacking you can get use the return type of a function, and use that as the type of `Props`.

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4002#issuecomment-344255679

---

However, I really like to be explicit here. It's very clear and keeps your type errors in the right place if you explicitly type `Props` and make `mapStateToProps` return the type `Props`.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State): Props => ({
  error: state.error, // error: ?string
})

type Props = {
  error: ?string,
}

class HelloWorld extends Component<Props> { ... }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HelloWorld)
```

This way if `State`'s `error` type changes, then you will get a type error in `mapStateToProps` because the value no longer conforms to `Props`. And fixing this is far easier to trying to make sense of inferred types throwing errors in the deep down guts of code where these values are used.

It is less DRY, but the errors it presents when things don't match will be far easier to debug.